# Get rid of empty space in v-select

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, v-select

I use Vuetify and have a question about access to styles of v-select input.
Actual result:
[image]

The desired result is to get rid of space between dots and arrow.

[image]

I went through the [official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#sass), but it didn't help.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="1">
          <v-select
            v-model="select"
            :items="items"
            item-text="state"
            return-object
            single-line
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[The full code example](https://codepen.io/tadvas/pen/KKvGoGV?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the existing style of one of the nested elements.

[image: existing style screenshot]

Add this to the style (example from your codepen):

```
.v-select__selection.v-select__selection--comma {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

I'd recommend adding a specific class (e.g. `wide-text-area` or something) to the `v-select` element and specify it in the CSS so the style doesn't apply to all elements without intention.

Comment: Well done, it works! Thank you. I forgot to override parent style with !important.